# C++ Confused about functions and vectors

Tags: c++

Hopefully this will be my last question for a while.

I'm a little confused as to why my function isn't working. Here is my code (I'll explain a little bit more afterwards):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


class Inventory {
public:
    void SetSumInv(int prcInDllrs, int individualquantity) {
        priceInDollars = priceInDollars + (prcInDllrs * individualquantity);
        totalInvPriceInDollars = totalInvPriceInDollars + priceInDollars;
    }
    void SetItemPrice(int whatever) {
        itemsPrice = whatever;
    }
    void SetName(string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    };
    void SetQuantity(int qnty)
    {
        quantity = qnty;
    };
    void SetAuthor(string athr) {
        author = athr;
    }
    void SetExpiration(string expir)
    {
        expiration = expir;
    };
    virtual void Print(){
        cout << name << " x" << quantity << " for: $" << itemsPrice; //" (Expires: " << expiration << ")";
        if (expiration.size() != 0) {
            cout << " (Expires: " << expiration << ")" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << " (Author: " << author << ")" << endl;
        }

    }
    void PrintInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to print." << endl;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i<inventory.size(); ++i) {
                cout << i << " - ";
                inventory.at(i)->Print();
            }
            cout << "Total inventory value: " << priceInDollars;
        }
        return;
    }
    void AddItemToInventory()
    {

    }
    vector<Inventory*> AddProduceToInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory)
    {
        Inventory* prdc;
        string usrInptName = "";
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";
        istringstream inSS;
        istringstream inDD;
        int usrInptQnty = 0;
        string usrInptExpr = "";
        string usrInptPrcStr = "";
        int usrInptPrc = 0;
        int ItemCost = 0;

        cout << "Enter name of new produce: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptName);
        SetName(usrInptName);

        cout << "Enter quantity: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS >> usrInptQnty;
        inSS.clear();
        SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);

        cout << "Enter expiration date: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptExpr);
        SetExpiration(usrInptExpr);
        cout << "Enter the price per item: $";
        getline(cin, usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD.str(usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD >> usrInptPrc;
        inDD.clear();
        SetItemPrice(usrInptPrc);

        ItemCost = (usrInptPrc * usrInptQnty);

        prdc = new Inventory;
        prdc->SetName(usrInptName);
        prdc->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        prdc->SetExpiration(usrInptExpr);
        prdc->SetSumInv(usrInptPrc, usrInptQnty);
        prdc->SetItemPrice(usrInptPrc);
        inventory.push_back(prdc);

        return inventory;
    }
    void AddBookToInventory()
    {
    }
    vector<Inventory*> AddBookToInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        Inventory* prdct;
        string usrInptName = "";
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";
        istringstream inSS;
        int usrInptQnty = 0;
        string usrInptAthr = "";
        string usrInptPrcStr = "";
        int usrInptPrc = 0;
        istringstream inDD;
        int sum = 0;
        int ItemCost = 0;

        cout << "Enter name of new book: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptName);

        cout << "Enter quantity: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS >> usrInptQnty;
        inSS.clear();

        cout << "Enter author: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptAthr);

        cout << "Enter the price per item: $";
        getline(cin, usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD.str(usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD >> usrInptPrc;
        inDD.clear();

        ItemCost = (usrInptPrc * usrInptQnty);

        prdct = new Inventory;
        prdct->SetName(usrInptName);
        prdct->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        prdct->SetSumInv(usrInptPrc, usrInptQnty);
        prdct->SetAuthor(usrInptAthr);
        prdct->SetItemPrice(usrInptPrc);

        inventory.push_back(prdct);


        return inventory;
    }
    void UpdateItemQtyInventory()
    {}
    //This is the update function in which we can change how many items a certain purchase has
    vector<Inventory*> UpdateItemQtyInInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";

        unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;

        istringstream inSS;

        string usrInptQntyStr = "";

        int usrInptQnty = 0;


        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to update." << endl;
        }
        else {
            PrintInventory(inventory);

            do {
                cout << "Update which item #: ";
                getline(cin, usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS.str(usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
                inSS.clear();
            } while (!(usrIndexChoice < inventory.size()));

            cout << "Enter new quantity: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS >> usrInptQnty;
            inSS.clear();

            inventory.at(usrIndexChoice)->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        }

        return inventory;
    }
    void RemoveItemFromInventory()
    {}
    //Here we will be removing an entire item from the inventory
    vector<Inventory*> RemoveItemFromInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        istringstream inSS;
        string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";
        unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";

        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to remove." << endl;
        }
        else {
            PrintInventory(inventory);

            do {
                cout << "Remove which item #: ";
                getline(cin, usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS.str(usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
                inSS.clear();
            } while (!(usrIndexChoice < inventory.size()));

            inventory.erase(inventory.begin() + usrIndexChoice);
        }

        return inventory;
    }
    void GetTotalValueAsPrice()
    {

    }
protected:
    string name;
    int    quantity = 0;
    int priceInDollars = 0;
    int totalCost = 0;
    int itemsPrice = 0;
    string expiration;
    string author;

private:
    int totalInvPriceInDollars = 0;
};

int main() {
    vector<Inventory*> INVENTORY;
    string usrInptOptn = "default";
    string usrInptOptn2 = "default";
    Inventory update;
    while (true) {
        // Get user choice
        cout << "\nEnter (p)rint, (a)dd, (u)pdate, (r)emove, or (q)uit: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptOptn);

        // Process user choice
        if (usrInptOptn.size() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'p') {
            update.PrintInventory(INVENTORY);               //Different! 
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'a') {///I don't know what the difference is between the three slashes and the two, but they are different!
            cout << "\nEnter (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptOptn2);

            if (usrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'b') {
                INVENTORY = update.AddBookToInventory(INVENTORY);                                   //Supposed to look like: INV = AddItem...(INV);
            }
        else if (usrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'p') {
                INVENTORY = update.AddProduceToInventory(INVENTORY);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'u') {
            INVENTORY = update.UpdateItemQtyInInventory(INVENTORY);
            }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'r') {
            INVENTORY = update.RemoveItemFromInventory(INVENTORY);
            }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'q') {
            cout << "\nGood bye." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So now. In my class Inventory, public: void SetSumInv, what this program does is it gets the user input, and tallies everything up, so when it prints, it is supposed to print the inventory and afterwards it is supposed to print the sum of the inventory value (in dollars). I've tried running this, and it won't print the sum of the inventory value. What is wrong here? I can't figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Um, yes... I'm not sure why you asked that. My debugger gives me absolutely no errors when I run this.

Comment: No offense. Did you step into every possible code path and print those relevant values to see whether they are correct?

Comment: When looping through the inventory vector, you never set `this->priceInDollars`, the value you print.

Comment: @Lorehead Where/how should I put that in? I've never used that before.

Comment: Right now, your output command says, `cout << "Total inventory value: " << priceInDollars;` (no `<< endl`).But you never update `priceInDollars`.  So you probably want to declare a temporary variable, initialize it to 0, and add the price of each item in the vector to it?

Comment: that isn't working @Lorehead , Any other ideas?

Comment: I don’t think I understand what you are trying to do.  Sorry.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas? I still can't get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues:
1.) priceInDollars was not being initialized properly
2.) totalInvPriceInDollars needs to be static

below code fixes the issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int totalInvPriceInDollars = 0 ;
class Inventory {
public:
    Inventory(): priceInDollars(0) {};
    void SetSumInv(int prcInDllrs, int individualquantity) {
        priceInDollars = priceInDollars + (prcInDllrs * individualquantity);
        totalInvPriceInDollars = totalInvPriceInDollars + priceInDollars;
    }
    void SetItemPrice(int whatever) {
        itemsPrice = whatever;
    }
    void SetName(string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    };
    void SetQuantity(int qnty)
    {
        quantity = qnty;
    };
    void SetAuthor(string athr) {
        author = athr;
    }
    void SetExpiration(string expir)
    {
        expiration = expir;
    };
    virtual void Print(){
        cout << name << " x" << quantity << " for: $" << itemsPrice; //" (Expires: " << expiration << ")";
        if (expiration.size() != 0) {
            cout << " (Expires: " << expiration << ")" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << " (Author: " << author << ")" << endl;
        }

    }
    void PrintInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to print." << endl;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i<inventory.size(); ++i) {
                cout << i << " - ";
                inventory.at(i)->Print();
            }
            cout << "Total inventory value: " << totalInvPriceInDollars;
        }
        return;
    }
    void AddItemToInventory()
    {

    }
    vector<Inventory*> AddProduceToInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory)
    {
        Inventory* prdc;
        string usrInptName = "";
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";
        istringstream inSS;
        istringstream inDD;
        int usrInptQnty = 0;
        string usrInptExpr = "";
        string usrInptPrcStr = "";
        int usrInptPrc = 0;
        int ItemCost = 0;

        cout << "Enter name of new produce: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptName);
        SetName(usrInptName);

        cout << "Enter quantity: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS >> usrInptQnty;
        inSS.clear();
        SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);

        cout << "Enter expiration date: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptExpr);
        SetExpiration(usrInptExpr);
        cout << "Enter the price per item: $";
        getline(cin, usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD.str(usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD >> usrInptPrc;
        inDD.clear();
        SetItemPrice(usrInptPrc);

        ItemCost = (usrInptPrc * usrInptQnty);

        prdc = new Inventory;
        prdc->SetName(usrInptName);
        prdc->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        prdc->SetExpiration(usrInptExpr);
        prdc->SetSumInv(usrInptPrc, usrInptQnty);
        prdc->SetItemPrice(usrInptPrc);
        inventory.push_back(prdc);

        return inventory;
    }
    void AddBookToInventory()
    {
    }
    vector<Inventory*> AddBookToInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        Inventory* prdct;
        string usrInptName = "";
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";
        istringstream inSS;
        int usrInptQnty = 0;
        string usrInptAthr = "";
        string usrInptPrcStr = "";
        int usrInptPrc = 0;
        istringstream inDD;
        int sum = 0;
        int ItemCost = 0;

        cout << "Enter name of new book: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptName);

        cout << "Enter quantity: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
        inSS >> usrInptQnty;
        inSS.clear();

        cout << "Enter author: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptAthr);

        cout << "Enter the price per item: $";
        getline(cin, usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD.str(usrInptPrcStr);
        inDD >> usrInptPrc;
        inDD.clear();

        ItemCost = (usrInptPrc * usrInptQnty);

        prdct = new Inventory;
        prdct->SetName(usrInptName);
        prdct->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        prdct->SetSumInv(usrInptPrc, usrInptQnty);
        prdct->SetAuthor(usrInptAthr);
        prdct->SetItemPrice(usrInptPrc);

        inventory.push_back(prdct);


        return inventory;
    }
    void UpdateItemQtyInventory()
    {}
    //This is the update function in which we can change how many items a certain purchase has
    vector<Inventory*> UpdateItemQtyInInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";

        unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;

        istringstream inSS;

        string usrInptQntyStr = "";

        int usrInptQnty = 0;


        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to update." << endl;
        }
        else {
            PrintInventory(inventory);

            do {
                cout << "Update which item #: ";
                getline(cin, usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS.str(usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
                inSS.clear();
            } while (!(usrIndexChoice < inventory.size()));

            cout << "Enter new quantity: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS >> usrInptQnty;
            inSS.clear();

            inventory.at(usrIndexChoice)->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        }

        return inventory;
    }
    void RemoveItemFromInventory()
    {}
    //Here we will be removing an entire item from the inventory
    vector<Inventory*> RemoveItemFromInventory(vector<Inventory*> inventory) {
        istringstream inSS;
        string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";
        unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";

        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to remove." << endl;
        }
        else {
            PrintInventory(inventory);

            do {
                cout << "Remove which item #: ";
                getline(cin, usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS.str(usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
                inSS.clear();
            } while (!(usrIndexChoice < inventory.size()));

            inventory.erase(inventory.begin() + usrIndexChoice);
        }

        return inventory;
    }
    void GetTotalValueAsPrice()
    {

    }
protected:
    string name;
    int    quantity;
    int priceInDollars ;
    int totalCost;
    int itemsPrice;
    string expiration;
    string author;

};

int main() {
    vector<Inventory*> INVENTORY;
    string usrInptOptn = "default";
    string usrInptOptn2 = "default";
    Inventory update;

    while (true) {
        // Get user choice
        cout << "\nEnter (p)rint, (a)dd, (u)pdate, (r)emove, or (q)uit: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptOptn);

        // Process user choice
        if (usrInptOptn.size() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'p') {
            update.PrintInventory(INVENTORY);               //Different! 
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'a') {///I don't know what the difference is between the three slashes and the two, but they are different!
            cout << "\nEnter (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptOptn2);

            if (usrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'b') {
                INVENTORY = update.AddBookToInventory(INVENTORY);                                   //Supposed to look like: INV = AddItem...(INV);
            }
            else if (usrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'p') {
                INVENTORY = update.AddProduceToInventory(INVENTORY);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'u') {
            INVENTORY = update.UpdateItemQtyInInventory(INVENTORY);
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'r') {
            INVENTORY = update.RemoveItemFromInventory(INVENTORY);
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'q') {
            cout << "\nGood bye." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for finding that! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

After dissecting your code; it took me considerable amount of time to clean some of it up. I did not have time to search for your bug, but what I was able to do was clean up your class a little bit so that it is friendlier to read. I made a couple of modifications to some of your class's function calls which are explained in the comments. I also removed all of the empty functions you had declared within your class. I also changed the look or feel of the classes naming conventions (this is user preference only)

**Inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

class Inventory {    
protected:
    std::string m_strName;
    std::string m_strExpiration;
    std::string m_strAuthor;

    int m_quantity;
    int m_priceInDollars;
    int m_totalCost;
    int m_itemsPrice;    

private:
    int m_totalInvPriceInDollars;

public:
    Inventory(); // Default Constructor

    void setName( const std::string& nm );
    void setAuthor( const std::string& athr );
    void setExpiration( const std::string& expir );

    void setSumInv( int prcInDllrs, int individualquantity ); 
    void setItemPrice( int whatever );   
    void setQuantity( int qnty );    

    virtual void print(); 
    void printInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& inventory ); 

    // I changed these methods to pass by reference opposed to returning from function call
    void addProduceToInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& inventory );   
    void addBookToInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& inventory ); 
    void updateItemQtyInInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& inventory ); 
    void removeItemFromInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& inventory ); 

}; // Invenotory

#endif // INVENTORY_H
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Inventory()
Inventory::Inventory() :
m_quantity( 0 ),
m_itemsPrice( 0 ),
m_priceInDollars( 0 ),
m_totalCost( 0 ),
m_totalInvPriceInDollars( 0 ) {
} // Inventory

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setSumInv()
void Inventory::setSumInv( int prcInDllrs, int individualquantity ) {
    m_priceInDollars = m_priceInDollars + (prcInDllrs * individualquantity);
    m_totalInvPriceInDollars = m_totalInvPriceInDollars + m_priceInDollars;
} // setSumInv

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setItemPrice()
void Inventory::setItemPrice( int whatever ) {
    m_itemsPrice = whatever;
} // setItemPrice

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setQuantity()
void Inventory::setQuantity( int qnty ) {
    m_quantity = qnty;
} // setQuantity

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setName()
void Inventory::setName( const std::string& strName ) {
    m_strName = strName;
} // setName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setAuthor()
void Inventory::setAuthor( const std::string& strAuthor ) {
    m_strAuthor = strAuthor;
} // setAuthor

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setExpiration()
void Inventory::setExpiration( const std::string& strExpir ) {
    m_strExpiration = strExpir;
} // setExpiration

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// print()
void Inventory::print() {
    std::cout << m_strName << " x" << m_quantity << " for: $" << m_itemsPrice; //" (Expires: " << expiration << ")";
    if ( m_strExpiration.size() != 0 ) {
        std::cout << " (Expires: " << m_strExpiration << ")" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << " (Author: " << m_strAuthor << ")" << std::endl;
    }
} // print

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// printInventory()
void Inventory::printInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& vInventory ) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    if ( vInventory.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << "No items to print." << std::endl;
    } else {
        for ( i = 0; i < vInventory.size(); ++i ) {
            std::cout << i << " - ";
            vInventory.at(i)->print();
        }
        std::cout << "Total inventory value: " << m_priceInDollars;
    }
} // printInventory

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// addProduceToInventory()
void Inventory::addProduceToInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& vInventory ) {
    std::string usrInptName = "";
    std::string usrInptQntyStr = "";
    std::istringstream inSS;
    std::istringstream inDD;
    int usrInptQnty = 0;
    std::string usrInptExpr = "";
    std::string usrInptPrcStr = "";
    int usrInptPrc = 0;
    int itemCost = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter name of new produce: ";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptName );
    setName( usrInptName );

    std::cout << "Enter quantity: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, usrInptQntyStr );
    inSS.str( usrInptQntyStr );
    inSS >> usrInptQnty;
    inSS.clear();
    setQuantity( usrInptQnty );

    std::cout << "Enter expiration date: ";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptExpr );
    setExpiration( usrInptExpr );
    std::cout << "Enter the price per item: $";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptPrcStr );
    inDD.str( usrInptPrcStr );
    inDD >> usrInptPrc;
    inDD.clear();
    setItemPrice( usrInptPrc );

    itemCost = usrInptPrc * usrInptQnty;

    Inventory* pInv = nullptr;   // Initialize Pointers to nullptr 
    pInv = new Inventory;        // Using New Memory (Dyanamic) - Where Is This Being Deleted?
    pInv->setName( usrInptName );
    pInv->setQuantity( usrInptQnty );
    pInv->setExpiration( usrInptExpr );
    pInv->setSumInv( usrInptPrc, usrInptQnty );
    pInv->setItemPrice(usrInptPrc);
    vInventory.push_back( pInv );

} // addProduceToInventory 

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// addBookToInventory()
void Inventory::addBookToInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& inventory) {   
    std::string usrInptName = "";
    std::string usrInptQntyStr = "";
    std::istringstream inSS;
    int usrInptQnty = 0;
    std::string usrInptAthr = "";
    std::string usrInptPrcStr = "";
    int usrInptPrc = 0;
    std::istringstream inDD;
    int sum = 0;
    int itemCost = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter name of new book: ";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptName );

    std::cout << "Enter quantity: ";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptQntyStr );
    inSS.str( usrInptQntyStr );
    inSS >> usrInptQnty;
    inSS.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter author: ";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptAthr );

    std::cout << "Enter the price per item: $";
    getline( std::cin, usrInptPrcStr );
    inDD.str( usrInptPrcStr );
    inDD >> usrInptPrc;
    inDD.clear();

    itemCost = usrInptPrc * usrInptQnty;

    Inventory* pInv = nullptr;   // Initialize pointers to nullptr;
    pInv = new Inventory;        // Using New Memory (Dyanamic) - Where Is This Being Deleted?
    pInv->setName( usrInptName );
    pInv->setQuantity( usrInptQnty );
    pInv->setSumInv( usrInptPrc, usrInptQnty );
    pInv->setAuthor( usrInptAthr );
    pInv->setItemPrice( usrInptPrc );
    inventory.push_back( pInv );

} // addBookToInventory

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// updateItemQtyInInventory()
// This is the update function in which we can change how many items a certain purchase has
void Inventory::updateItemQtyInInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& vInventory ) {
    std::string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";        
    unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;
    std::istringstream inSS;
    std::string usrInptQntyStr = "";
    int usrInptQnty = 0;

    if ( vInventory.size() == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "No items to update." << std::endl;
    } else {
        printInventory( vInventory );

        do {
            std::cout << "Update which item #: ";
            getline( std::cin, usrIndexChoiceStr );
            inSS.str( usrIndexChoiceStr );
            inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
            inSS.clear();
        } while ( !(usrIndexChoice < vInventory.size()) );

        std::cout << "Enter new quantity: ";
        getline( std::cin, usrInptQntyStr );
        inSS.str( usrInptQntyStr );
        inSS >> usrInptQnty;
        inSS.clear();

        vInventory.at(usrIndexChoice)->setQuantity(usrInptQnty);
    }
} // updateItemQtyInInventory

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// removeItemFromInventory()
// Here we will be removing an entire item from the inventory
void Inventory::removeItemFromInventory( std::vector<Inventory*>& vInventory) {
    std::istringstream inSS;
    std::string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";
    unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;
    std::string usrInptQntyStr = "";

    if ( vInventory.size() == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "No items to remove." << std::endl;
    } else {
        printInventory( vInventory );

        do {
            std::cout << "Remove which item #: ";
            getline( std::cin, usrIndexChoiceStr );
            inSS.str( usrIndexChoiceStr );
            inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
            inSS.clear();
        } while ( !(usrIndexChoice < vInventory.size()) );

        vInventory.erase( vInventory.begin() + usrIndexChoice );
    }
} // removeItemFromInventory
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

//using namespace std; // Bad Practice To Use This In A Global Scope! 
#include "Inventory.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main()
int main() {
    std::vector<Inventory*> vInventory;
    std::string strUsrInptOptn = "default";
    std::string strUsrInptOptn2 = "default";
    Inventory update;

    while (true) {
        // Get user choice
        std::cout << "\nEnter (p)rint, (a)dd, (u)pdate, (r)emove, or (q)uit: ";
        getline( std::cin, strUsrInptOptn);

        // Process user choice
        if ( strUsrInptOptn.size() == 0 ) {
            continue;

        } else if ( strUsrInptOptn.at(0) == 'p' ) {
            update.printInventory( vInventory );      //Different!

        } else if ( strUsrInptOptn.at(0) == 'a' ) { ///I don't know what the difference is between the three slashes and the two, but they are different!
            std::cout << "\nEnter (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
            getline( std::cin, strUsrInptOptn2 );

            if ( strUsrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'b' ) {
                update.addBookToInventory( vInventory );    //Supposed to look like: INV = AddItem...(INV);

            } else if ( strUsrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'p' ) {
                update.addProduceToInventory( vInventory );

            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else if ( strUsrInptOptn.at(0) == 'u' ) {
            update.updateItemQtyInInventory( vInventory );

        } else if ( strUsrInptOptn.at(0) == 'r' ) {
            update.removeItemFromInventory( vInventory );

        } else if ( strUsrInptOptn.at(0) == 'q') {
            std::cout << "\nGood bye." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    } // while

    return 0;
} // main
```

With this the code is much cleaner looking with an elegant feel. The `main.cpp` isn't cluttered with tons of lines of code; it is always good practice to keep `main.cpp` short and simple since this is where the main executable starts. I created a class of your inventory and put it in its own module in a `*.h` and `*.cpp` file. I also separated its declaration from its definition or its implementation. This way if someone else is looking at your source code to use it; they do not have to know exactly how the function works, only what it is supposed to do. The interface or `*.h` file should tell you everything you need to know about the class object and how it is used. Also this allows for cleaner and quicker build times since you only have to compile this class's `*.cpp` file only when you changed something within instead of rebuilding the entire solution.

Now there are some instances where you might want to have the implementation in the header file and some cases where you don't have a choice and it has to be. The cases where you might want the implementation to be in the header file is if your methods are declared as `inline` or you are creating a header only library. The case where you may not have a choice but to have it in the header file is if you are creating `class templates` or `function templates` however when you have these two types either `inline member functions`, `class template member functions` or `function templates` these will usually be found in an inline file or an `*.inl` and you would include this file using the `#include` directive outside of your class's declaration and before the `#endif` header guard; if you are using `#pragma once` instead of the `#ifndef #define #endif` then you would just have this after the class's declaration.

Once you start to have a constant structure of your code that you prefer; it will become easier to debug and find errors.

Out side of your question I think I have noticed another bug that you have introduced that you may or may not be aware of; I think you may have a memory leak in your program!

I hope this serves as a guide to help you. If I get the chance within the next couple of days; I may go ahead and either try to debug your code or try to rewrite your program in a slightly more elegant way. If I do get around to it I'll post it as another answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for putting all that effort into this! If you can, I'd still like to see your version of the program. I'll also try to keep my programs neater in the future. :D

Comment: No problem at all; I am self taught and never had any formal training. Everything that I know and have learned over the years was either from reading books, online tutorials and trial and error. If I can take what I have learned and share it with others to save them time and many headaches it is all the more worth it.

Comment: I may work on this later tonight if I'm not to busy.

Comment: I have the bulk of this done; I'm just working out some bugs and fine tuning it. I should have it done in another day or so.

Comment: @Danny I have added a new answer with a working program.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a version of the program that the user had requested. It took me a little bit of time to work out the bugs and to make sure that it is working as expected. This doesn't meant that it is completely bug free. If anyone happens to find any bugs please feel free to comment and list any bugs so that I can fix them and make the appropriate edits.

This program is written in C++ using Win32 Console Application compiled and built with VS 2015.

What I have done here is created a small class hierarchy. The `StoreItem` class is an abstract base class meaning you can not create an object of this type directly since its constructors are protected. Any class object that inherits from this base class can be constructed publicly. I did this since different product types may have different information about them.

I took what was common about all Product Types and stored that information into the base class using protected members and public access functions. The only private member in the base class is the `Type` the inherited class is upon construction. These are just objects that contain data and methods. The `Inventory` class is what does a majority of the work to store and remove items, to calculate totals and to print its list.

I designed it this way so that the `StoreItem` and its inherited classes do not have any dependences with the `iostream` objects. The Inventory class only uses the `std::cout` objects within its printing method.

The only section of code that works with the input or the `std::cin` object is within the `main` function in the working while loop.

Having a structure such as this, allows these classes to be modular, or reusable. This also makes it easy to add another type or store item. You would have to create another class that is derived from StoreItem, Add in the Enumerated type, then repeat the process of adding in the appropriate functions within the Inventory and within the user choice branching.

This could be simplified a little more but I tried to keep this as close to the user's original program. I did not elect to use generic template types which is also a very useful and an efficient way of implementing it to reduce the amount of code redundancy. One needs to master these basic concepts before they can begin to move onto more advanced topics.

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
//#include <sstream> // Not Using stringstring, istringstream, or ostringstream
#include <vector>

#endif // STDAFX_H
```

**stdafx.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

**StoreItem.h**

```
#ifndef STORE_ITEM_H
#define STORE_ITEM_H

class StoreItem {
public:
    enum ItemType {
        ITEM_BOOK = 0,
        ITEM_PRODUCE,
    }; // ItemType

protected:
    std::string     m_strItemName;
    float           m_priceInDollars;

private:
    ItemType m_type;

public:
    std::string getItemName() const;
    float       getItemPrice() const;

    void setItemName( const std::string& strItemName );
    void setItemPrice( float price );

    ItemType getItemType() const;

protected:
    explicit StoreItem( ItemType type );
    StoreItem( ItemType type, const std::string& strItemName, float priceInDollars );

}; // StoreItem

#endif // STORE_ITEM_H
```

**StoreItem.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StoreItem.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// StoreItem()
StoreItem::StoreItem( ItemType type ) :
m_type( type ) {
} // StoreItem

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// StoreItem()
StoreItem::StoreItem( ItemType type, const std::string& strItemName, float priceInDollars ) :
m_type( type ),
m_strItemName( strItemName ),
m_priceInDollars( priceInDollars ){
} // StoreItem

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getItemType()
StoreItem::ItemType StoreItem::getItemType() const {
    return m_type;
} // getItemType

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setItemName()
void StoreItem::setItemName( const std::string& strItemName ) {
    m_strItemName = strItemName;
} // setItemName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getItemName()
std::string StoreItem::getItemName() const {
    return m_strItemName;
} // getItemName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setItemPrice()
void StoreItem::setItemPrice( float priceInDollars ) {
    m_priceInDollars = priceInDollars;
} // setItemPrice

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getItemPrice()
float StoreItem::getItemPrice() const {
    return m_priceInDollars;
} // getItemPrice
```

**Book.h**

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include "StoreItem.h"

class Book sealed : public StoreItem {
private:
    std::string m_strAuthorName;

public:
    Book();
    Book( const std::string& strItemName, float priceInDollars, const std::string& strAuthor );

    void setAuthorName( const std::string& strAuthor );
    std::string getAuthorName() const;

}; // Book

#endif // BOOK_H
```

**Book.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Book.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Book()
Book::Book() :
StoreItem( ITEM_BOOK ) {
} // Book

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Book()
Book::Book( const std::string& strItemName, float priceInDollars, const std::string& strAuthorName ) :
StoreItem( ITEM_BOOK, strItemName, priceInDollars ),
m_strAuthorName( strAuthorName ) {
} // Book

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setAuthorName()
void Book::setAuthorName( const std::string& strAuthorName ) {
    m_strAuthorName = strAuthorName;
} // setAuthorName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getAuthorName()
std::string Book::getAuthorName() const {
    return m_strAuthorName;
} // getAuthorName
```

**Produce.h**

```
#ifndef PRODUCE_H
#define PRODUCE_H

#include "StoreItem.h"

class Produce sealed : public StoreItem {
private:
    std::string m_strExpirationDate;

public:
    Produce();
    Produce( const std::string& strItemName, float priceInDollars, const std::string& strExpirationDate );

    void setExpirationDate( const std::string& strExpirationDate );
    std::string getExpirationDate() const;

}; // Produce

#endif // PRODUCE_H
```

**Produce.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Produce.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Produce()
Produce::Produce() :
StoreItem( ITEM_PRODUCE ) {
} // Produce

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Produce()
Produce::Produce( const std::string& strItemName, float priceInDollars, const std::string& strExpirationDate ) :
StoreItem( ITEM_PRODUCE, strItemName, priceInDollars ),
m_strExpirationDate( strExpirationDate ) {
} // Produce

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setExpirationDate()
void Produce::setExpirationDate( const std::string& strExpirationDate ) {
    m_strExpirationDate = strExpirationDate;
} // setExpirationDate

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getExpirationDate()
std::string Produce::getExpirationDate() const {
    return m_strExpirationDate;
} // getExpirationDate
```

**Inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include "StoreItem.h" // Needed For StoreItem::ItemType

class Book;
class Produce;

class Inventory {
private:
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Book>>      PtrBooks;
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Produce>>   PtrProduce;

    PtrBooks    m_vBooks;
    PtrProduce  m_vProduce;

public:
    void addBook( const std::string& strName, const std::string& strAuthor, float price );
    void addProduce( const std::string& strName, const std::string& strExpiration, float price );

    void removeItemFromIventory( StoreItem::ItemType type, const std::string& strItemName, unsigned idx );

    void showInventory() const;

    bool isBookListEmpty() const;
    bool isProduceListEmpty() const;

}; // Inventory
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Inventory.h"

#include "Book.h"
#include "Produce.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// addBook()
void Inventory::addBook( const std::string& strName, const std::string& strAuthor, float price ) {
    m_vBooks.push_back( std::shared_ptr<Book>( new Book( strName, price, strAuthor ) ) );
} // addItemTo

// addProduce()
void Inventory::addProduce( const std::string& strName, const std::string& strExpiration, float price ) {
    m_vProduce.push_back( std::shared_ptr<Produce>( new Produce( strName, price, strExpiration ) ) );
} // addProduce

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// removeItemFromInventory()
void Inventory::removeItemFromIventory( StoreItem::ItemType type, const std::string& strItemName, unsigned idx ) {
    if ( strItemName.empty() ) {
        // throw Exeption Here
        return;
    }

    unsigned counter = 1; // User Based, Not Vector or Array Based

    if ( type == StoreItem::ITEM_BOOK ) {
        PtrBooks::iterator it = m_vBooks.begin();
        for ( ; it != m_vBooks.end(); ++it ) {
            if ( it->get()->getItemName() == strItemName && counter == idx ) {
                // Found It
                it->reset();
                m_vBooks.erase( it );
                return;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

    // Reset Counter
    counter = 1;
    if ( type == StoreItem::ITEM_PRODUCE ) {
        PtrProduce::iterator it = m_vProduce.begin();
        for ( ; it != m_vProduce.end(); ++it ) {
            if ( it->get()->getItemName() == strItemName && counter == idx ) {
                // Found It
                it->reset();
                m_vProduce.erase( it );
                return;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

} // removeItemFromInventory()

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// showInventory()
void Inventory::showInventory() const {
    float totalCostBooks = 0;
    float totalCostProduce = 0;

    std::flush( std::cout );

    std::cout << "\n-------------" << std::endl
              << "Sales Invoice" << std::endl 
              << "-------------" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Book Information: " << std::endl;
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < m_vBooks.size(); ++u ) {
        std::cout << u + 1 << ": " 
                  << m_vBooks.at( u ).get()->getItemName() << " " 
                  << m_vBooks.at( u ).get()->getAuthorName() << " "  
                  << "$" << m_vBooks.at( u ).get()->getItemPrice() << std::endl;

        totalCostBooks += m_vBooks.at( u ).get()->getItemPrice();
    }
    std::cout << "Total Cost Of Books: $" << totalCostBooks << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Produce Information: " << std::endl;
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < m_vProduce.size(); ++u ) {
        std::cout << u + 1 << ": "
                  << m_vProduce.at( u ).get()->getItemName() << " "
                  << m_vProduce.at( u ).get()->getExpirationDate() << " "
                  << "$" << m_vProduce.at( u ).get()->getItemPrice() << std::endl;

        totalCostProduce += m_vProduce.at( u ).get()->getItemPrice();
    }
    std::cout << "Total Cost Of Produce: $" << totalCostProduce << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl
              << "Grand Total: $" << totalCostBooks + totalCostProduce << std::endl;

} // showInventory

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isBookListEmpty()
bool Inventory::isBookListEmpty() const {
    return m_vBooks.empty();
} // isBookListEmpty

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isProduceListEmpty()
bool Inventory::isProduceListEmpty() const {
    return m_vProduce.empty();
} // isProduceListEmpty
```

**main.cpp**

```
// StoreInventory.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Inventory.h"

int main() {
    Inventory inventory;
    std::string userInput;

    bool quit = false;
    while ( !quit ) {       

        std::cout << "\nEnter (a)dd, (r)emove, (s)how inventory, (q)uit: ";
        std::cin >> userInput;

        if ( userInput[0] == 'a' || userInput[0] == 'A' ) {

            std::cout << "\nEnter (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
            std::cin >> userInput;

            if ( userInput[0] == 'b' || userInput[0] == 'B' ) {
                std::string strName;
                std::string strAuthor;
                float price = 0;

                std::cout << "\nEnter the name of the book. ";
                std::getline( std::cin, strName ); // For Some Reason I have To Add This Twice
                std::getline( std::cin, strName );

                std::cout << "\nEnter the book's author. ";
                std::getline( std::cin, strAuthor );

                std::cout << "\nEnter the price in US Dollars. ";
                std::cin >> price;

                inventory.addBook( strName, strAuthor, price );
            } else if ( userInput[0] == 'p' || userInput[0] == 'P' ) {
                std::string strName;
                std::string strExpiration;
                float price = 0;

                std::cout << "\nEnter the type of produce. ";
                std::getline( std::cin, strName ); // For Some Reason I have To Add This Twice
                std::getline( std::cin, strName );

                std::cout << "\nEnter the expiration date. ";
                std::getline( std::cin, strExpiration );

                std::cout << "\nEnter the price in US Dollars. ";
                std::cin >> price;

                inventory.addProduce( strName, strExpiration, price );          
            } else {
                std::cout << "\nInvalid Entry\n";
            }
            system( "cls" ); // If on windows and using win32 console
            continue;

        } else if ( userInput[0] == 'r' || userInput[0] == 'R' ) {
            // Clear The Screen, Show The Inventory Then Ask User Which Item To Remove
            system( "cls" ); // If on windows and using win32 console

            inventory.showInventory();

            std::cout << "\nWhich item would you like to remove (b)ook or (p)roduce? ";
            std::cin >> userInput;

            StoreItem::ItemType type;

            if ( userInput[0] == 'b' || userInput[0] == 'B' ) {
                if ( inventory.isBookListEmpty() ) {
                    std::cout << "\nThere are no entries availabe to remove. ";
                    continue;
                } else {
                    type = StoreItem::ITEM_BOOK;
                }
            } else if ( userInput[0] == 'p' || userInput[0] == 'P' ) {
                if ( inventory.isProduceListEmpty() ) {
                    std::cout << "\nThere are no entries available to remove. ";
                    continue;
                } else {
                    type  = StoreItem::ITEM_PRODUCE;
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << "\nInvalid Type\n";
            }

            std::string strName;
            unsigned idx;

            std::cout << "\nEnter name of product you wish to remove. ";
            std::getline( std::cin, strName ); // For Some Reason I have To Add This Twice
            std::getline( std::cin, strName );

            std::cout << "\nEnter item number of this type you wish to remove. ";
            std::cin >> idx;

            inventory.removeItemFromIventory( type, strName, idx );
            continue;

        }  else  if ( userInput[0] == 's' || userInput[0] == 'S' ) {
            system( "cls" ); // If on windows and using win32 console
            inventory.showInventory();
            continue;
        } else if ( userInput[0] == 'q' || userInput[0] == 'Q' ) {
            quit = true;
            break;  
        } else {
            std::cout << "\nInvalid Entry\n";
            continue;
        }           
    } // while

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();

    return 0;
} // main
```